# Why don't constructor values inherit property limitations

Tags: java

Why is the property definition of LifeCycle not enough, why does my constructor need to also define it as an ArrayList()?  Even so, why doesn't my ArrayList inherit the limitation of `<LifeCycle>` from the property definition?  I don't like having to set it in both places, seems very redundant.

```
class Search {
    private Collection<LifeCycle> lifeCycleCollection;

    public Search() {
        this.lifeCycleCollection = new ArrayList<LifeCycle>();
    }
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collection is an interface, when you create the instance you are actually specifying the implementation.

As to your question about Generics, as with Java 7 you can also write

```
lifeCycleCollection = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I wasn't asking how to make it Generic, I was asking why do I need to specify `ArrayList<LifeCycle>` when I've already defined that in the `Collection`

Answer (score 2):

[Alessio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10129543/348975) is  correct.  You can also tighten up the code by one line by moving stuff from the constructor.

```
class Search {
    private Collection<LifeCycle> lifeCycleCollection = new ArrayList<>();

    public Search() {
    }
```